# Missing xml config tabs in Eclipse?

Tags: xml, eclipse

I am following a set of tutorials and they are great, but he keeps referencing a set of tabs at the bottom of his XML files to configure them, but I don't have them. I followed his instructions and installed all the same plugins, but they aren't there. On his tutorial, there was a **beans** tab for a Spring Beans `beans.xml` file and a **dependancy** tab for the Maven `pom.xml`.

I am using Eclipse EE Kepler, Spring IDE, and Maven.

### The tab in the tutorial

[image: The tab in the tutorial]

### What I see

[image: what I see]

Comment: Try right-clicking on the file and manually selecting the editor to open with. Eclipse may be remembering (incorrectly) to open them in the generic XML editor.

Comment: @chrylis that was it. Thank you so much. This was driving me crazy and I was thinking it was something wrong with my configuration or plugin setup.

Comment: I have the same problem and the solution here doesn't work. So I try to right click on the xml and I searched for "spring config editor", but there is no such option. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse remembers which editor you've used to open specific files (in this case, the generic XML editor) and sometimes uses that editor even if you later install a plugin that provides a more specific editor (such as the Spring Beans editor). Right-click the file and manually select "open with $EDITOR".

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with eclipse luna, but it has not shown me the Spring Editor (but Spring was installed in newest version)....
now I gave up and installed STS from http://spring.io/tools/sts/all - finally the editor works fine =)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried installing different plugins for eclipse as well as STS in an existing Eclipse installation. Finally I ended up using
[Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all) instead of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If someone just wants to add a new bean & can't find the correct perspective, the best way to create a new bean is as follows.

1. Right-click on the **beans.xml** file.
2. Now click **New bean definition**.
3. Configure your bean, click finish.